# Matlab 2014a for Linux hangs on print / saveas

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-figure, freeze

i am using Matlab 2014a on Linux (OpenSuse Leap 42.1). Matlab renders plots as usual but i cannot save the plot to any file because it hangs itself during any call to `saveas` or `print`. This for example

```
saveas(gcf,pngname,'png')
```

makes Matlab completely freeze and i need to kill it manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen also on the simple cases, like `saveas(figure(), 'test.png');` ?

Comment: I am also using Linux but another distribution and Matlab 2015b, it works for me. I am not sure if it helps but maybe you could debug and step through the code, i.e. `saveas` calls `print` etc. - maybe you can identify a problematic step?

Comment: Try `print -dpng pngname`.

Comment: I've tried `saveas(figure(), 'test.png')` and this works. If, however, I try to plot figure first, and then save manually with `saveas(figure(1),'test.png')`, Matlab freezes...The same thing happens with `print -dpng pngname`...